# Crack http basic auth password from Linux

Tags: linux, password, nessus

I have a network camera, where the default password does not work. It is probably something simple though, so I though I should try a stock password breaker. What should I use to try to crack my network camera's basic auth login/password on port 80 on my local network? Nessus?

Comment: [ncrack](http://nmap.org/ncrack/)

Comment: What model of network camera? What is the setup? If the password is in the camera itself, have you looked at the manufacturer's site for a "emergency" password, or a way of "full factory reset"?

Answer (score 1):

Do a full factory reset on your camera as suggested by @vonbrand. Consult your camera manual to find out how to achieve a full factory reset. The manual should also document the default password after factory reset.

Answer (score 0):

If you have root/sudo access, it'd be much, much easier to reset the password directly:

`sudo passwd foo` where 'foo' is the account owner of the camera.

If you don't have root access, ask for permission from whomever has it.

Comment: Oh, did I perhaps misunderstand? Is this actually living a life of its own?

Comment: I'm guessing OP doesn't have OS-level access to the security camera.